# Jmeter - group results in listener based on response code or variable

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm preparing a load test for a web service and I'm almost done but I have one problem. Right now I have some listeners, for example graphs, one for successful samples and the other for failures only. 
I want to be able to create more listeners or perhaps a column in a table somewhere that will tell me how much time did the service take to run when there were no errors, when error "A" occured (response code... or variable..), error "B" etc. along with how many times these errors occured.

So an example of the output would be something like:

```
Success | 1000 | avg 32ms   | max 120 ms | min 20 ms, ...
Errors  |  300 | avg 50 ms  | max 300 ms | min 10 ms, ...
Error A |  100 | avg 10 ms  | max 20 ms  | min 8 ms, ...
Error B |   54 | avg 100 ms | max 200 ms | min 60 ms, ...
```

etc. etc.

Is it possible in JMeter? If so, how? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible, add a listener.`View results in Table` and Configure it with what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this listner isn't really what I need, I need something like Summary Report

Comment: ok take a look at my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11191109/169277 or this question that was asked, that might be what you need

Answer (score 1):

1) Look first onto existent custom listeners on the [Jmeter Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) project:

- [Response Codes per Second](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond)
- [Page Data Extractor](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PageDataExtractor)

and try either use they as is or try to adopt they or jmeter's out-of-box listeners for your needs (sources for both the projects are available).

2) You can also process jmeter-generated results file (.jtl) in your own manner to get what you need:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669467/jmeter-how-to-create-summary-report-from-jtl-file
- [html-reports using Jmeter Ant task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm already familiar with Jmeter Plugins, but I'll try and manage somehow with the second option. Thanks!